# Audio on off button in webview, when switched off the sound plays in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, webview

```
function audioOnOff(){
    if(audio){
        muteAllAudios();
        audio = false;
    }
    else{
        unmuteAllAudios();
        audio = true;
    }
    settingsScreen();

}
function muteAllAudios(){

    correctAnswerSound.muted = true;
    wrongAnswerSound.muted = true;
    boingSound.muted = true;
    wisemanSound.muted = true;
    professorSound.muted = true;
}
function unmuteAllAudios(){

    correctAnswerSound.muted = false;
    wrongAnswerSound.muted = false;
    boingSound.muted = false;
    wisemanSound.muted = false;
    professorSound.muted = false;
```

I have a button in webView to on/off audio settings, but when I turn off the audio the sound still plays in my iOS app. What is the solution?

Comment: try alerting some text in both muteall and unmuteall functions as see if they are being called. Let's know the result of this so we can help further

Comment: yes akshay i will let you know

Comment: it works fine in android but it doesnt works in iOS akshay.. if there was a problem in js then the same would be seen in android, but the scenario is that it works in android......

Comment: I think android and IOS do not utilize the sasme webkit version. That may be a cause for this behaviour

Comment: are you not getting any alerts at all?

Comment: yeah let me check with it and let you know once the problem is solved

Comment: yes it shows alert Akshay, what i wanted is that im loading a webview which is a game and its functionalities are written in java script. When i get into the game settings and turn Audio Off the Sound is even played while running the game. Android team solved this by using a single line as follows : uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"                                  no idea how it can be done in iOS never worked in Hybrid Apps :(

Comment: Any solution would be great. Just gonna check running those application in 3 different  versions of iOS (i.e) 7, 8 & 9.